# Is there a way to render .jsx components inside express server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm very confused about mixing express routes with React and .jsx files.
I'm trying to build a multipage website with a mongoose database and I've been using ejs to do it. now I'm trying to convert to React but I have absolutely no idea of how to do this despite my research for 3 days.
What I'm looking to do is roughly something like this (example is a react component "example.jsx")

`app.get("/",function(req,res){ res.send(<example />)})`

instead of

`app.get("/",function(req,res){ res.send("another.ejs") })`

If I cant do such a thing would you recommend React routs or just sticking with ejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to (**1.**) convert the JSX code to Javascript, and then (**2.**) render the Javascript into an HTML string, which you then can send to the client.

E.g. if you have the file `example.js`:

```
console.log('jsxData:', <example />);
// app.get("/",function(req,res){ res.send(<example />)})
```

#### 1. Transpile JSX to Javascript

If a Javascript file contains JSX code, it becomes a JSX file, and Javascript can't understand it anymore. The extension .js or .jsx doesn't matter here. You may or may not rename it to `example.jsx`, if you like.

But you can convert (aka. "transpile") that JSX file into a Javascript file with [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/). You will get a new, separate file which is a valid Javascript file.

**1.a.** If it's not already installed, you need to install babel and the JSX transpiler *(For the installation I'm using [yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/) here, [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/) is also possible)*:

```
yarn add @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-react --dev
```

**1.b.** Convert the JSX file to Javascript:

```
yarn babel example.js --presets=@babel/preset-react --out-dir dist
```

Now you should have the new file `/dist/example.js`, which is a valid Javascript file (but still not an HTML file). *(The extension of this file will be `.js`, not matter if the original source file was `.js` or `.jsx`.)*

#### 2. Render HTML

In step 1. you have transpiled the JSX code `<example />` inside your original file into the Javascript code `React.createElement("example", null)` inside the transpiled file, but this is still not HTML, this is a Javascript "React element".

You can use [ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) to render this React element into HTML:

**2.a.** In case it's not already installed, then install [`react` and `react-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom):

```
yarn add react react-dom
```

**2.b.** Import `react` and `react-dom/server`, and use the `renderToString()` method to render the React element into an HTML string:

```
const React = require('react'); // <-- React is required, because it is used in the transpiled .js file.
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

const jsxData = <example />;
const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString( jsxData );

console.log('htmlString:', htmlString);
// app.get("/",function(req,res){ res.send( htmlString )})
```

Transpile this JSX file again as before. Now inside the `./dist/example.js` the `htmlString` should contain the HTML string which you can send to the client. In this example, if you run e.g. `node ./dist/example.js` you should see the console output:

```
htmlString: <example data-reactroot=""></example>
```

Comment: thanks. so from what I understand we need to convert jsx to js using babel then to html using react. but do I need to transpile jsx each time I make a change to it? and how can I send props?

Comment: yes, you have to transpile JSX to JS on every change. That's exactly what happens in the frontend too, but it's usually automated ([webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), hot-reloading, etc.). To make the tranferred html code work with React on the frontend you have to "[hydrate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate)" it.

Comment: BTW. if you just want a React website (not specifically use JSX code in the backend), then you probably want to create just a static 'index.html' page and do all the JSX magic on the client (instead of on the server), which would be the most common approach. See [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can understand what's going on.

Comment: I know we can use react in a separated front-end project and its easier but I came here because I want to make React components is SSR